# How to isolate a button in Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, tkinter

As shown in the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbrOV.png), every button is activated. It's like I'm holding over every button, at once.

What is the solution to this?

And yes, the naming isn't perfect. But I swear to god, I can not break the habit. Been doing it for close to 5 years. I am revisiting Tkinter, as I have not used it in quite a few years, and can not seem to find the solution

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
window = tk.Tk()

window.title("GUI Test")

Dab = tk.Button(window, text="Start", width="10", height="10")


Dab1 = tk.Button(window, text="Start", width="10", height="10")

def open_popup():
   top = tk.Toplevel(window)
   top.geometry("750x250")
   top.title("Child")
   tk.Label(top, text= "Window", font=('Mistral 18 bold')).place(x=150,y=80)

Dab2= tk.Button(window, text="Start", width="10", height="10", command = open_popup)


Dab3 = tk.Button(window, text="Start", width="10", height="10")



Dab.pack()

Dab1.pack()

Dab2.pack()

Dab3.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a `tk.Radiobutton` instead maybe? I'm not exactly clear on what the issue is.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this setup.

Comment: No, I it's not a radiobutton. When I click, every single button clicks too. It is like I'm holding over every button at once, even when the cursor is no where near.

Comment: [link](https://filebin.net/vv68c57qni2i5os1). There it's displayed. Edit: Link is from filebin

Comment: How do you know that when you click one, they all click? The code you posted doesn't do anything when you click a button. When I run your code it seems to be operating as designed.

Comment: Are you certain _this_ code reproduces this behavior? You've clearly left some code out. Can you make sure that you provide a [mcve] that actually reproduces the problem?

Comment: When I move the mouse, every single button flickers. Am I misunderstanding, and this is normal behaviour? It seems weird to be

Comment: I don't see that behavior when I run the code you posted, with the minimal amount of extra lines to make it work.

Comment: Correction, it does not trigger every button, my apologies. However, it all buttons flicker. This is the whole code, and I have not seen this behaviour when working with Tkinter in the past. I have updated the question with all the code now.

Comment: Also @BryanOakley, I have posted a link to a video showing what I am experiencing. Does it have something to do with me being on a Mac? I would think its absolutely the same for Mac & Windows, at least with this.

Comment: I ran your code on a mac and it worked fine, though I don't use the version of tkinter that comes with the OS. The version that comes with the OS is a bit buggy.

Comment: Oh, okay. That may explain the issue, which version do you recommend?

Comment: I used Python 3.11.0rc2

Comment: Updating to python 3.10 seems to have fixed the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Updating to python3.10 seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks to everyone who helped!